# Redirect https with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I build a website and i want redirect http (local) to https (use online). I tried using middleware, using `AppServiceProvider`, `.htacess`, `RouteServiceProvider` but it didn't work.

1, When i use middleware

```html
class HttpsProtocol
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!app()->environment('local')) {
            // for Proxies
            Request::setTrustedProxies([$request->getClientIp()], 
                Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL);

            if (!$request->isSecure()) {
                return redirect()->secure($request->path(), 301);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    
    }
}
```

2, When i use .htancess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

3, when i use AppServiceProvider

```html
public function boot()
    {
        if (!app()->environment('local')) {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
        //
    }
```

When use get method
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXiRG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tZz0.png

It created another https link and can run.
But when i use check slug automatic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv8rh.png

and when i use Post method

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vKOD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAoMD.png
It didn't make it to https,
Please help me !
(Sorry because my english)

Comment: We don't debug images!

Comment: First, you need to fix the image.
Then you need to provide more information about what you tried on your `Middleware`, `AppServiceProvider` , `.htaccess`, `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: ok thank for feedback and i have added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open **AppServiceProvider** and add

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

in the boot function. thats all.

```
    public function boot()
    {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```